# asp-page route not rendering url to admin subfolders

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I have created few page in asp.net core 3.1 Razor page web application for educational purpose as i am new to asp.net core, I am facing strang issue with one of route of of page `asp-page="/Admin/News"` all othe routes work fine but when i added another link for admin page `asp-page="/Admin/News"` its not working it shows the nav items but always points to the same page i am in for example if i am on `Employee` and if i click on Admin Section`it will go to`Employee` as i was on this page.

Not sure why this is happening, i changed `asp-page="/Admin/News"` to `asp-page="/Admin/News/"`, `asp-page="/Admin/News/Index"` even these routes dont work

```
<ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/BookList/Index">Book</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Employee">Employee</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/News">News</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Admin/News">Admin Section</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

I am also attaching code & folder screenshot
[image]

i am able to access page if i type page url directly `https://localhost:44364/Admin/News/`

**Startup.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using BookListRazor.Data;
using BookListRazor.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace BookListRazor
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


            var sqlConnectionConfiguration = new SqlConnectionConfiguration(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            services.AddSingleton(sqlConnectionConfiguration);

            //services.AddTransient<IEmployeeService, EmployeeDapperService>();
            services.AddScoped<IEmployeeService, EmployeeDapperService>();
            services.AddScoped<INewsService, NewsService>();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: /Admin/News/Index should work , show your startup.cs please .

Comment: @NanYu, i have updated question with startup.cs details.It looked for any reference on internet but could not find any solution few options suggested adding `asp-route-roleId="1" asp-route-userId="2"` that even that dint work.  for now is am using it as simple anchor which works`<a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/Admin/News/" >Admin Section</a>` till i find what is wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

In your */Admin/News/Index.cshtml* add:

```
@page "/Admin/News/"
```